# custom text area in the following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textbox

please can anyone help me in making the text area in the following code to appear on all the area of the save button. I have provided the code of the whole page. i have used cdn hosted jquery.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <style>
            /* App custom styles from google and microsoft*/
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textarea1">
                            <h1 style='text-align:center;'>Please enter your notes here
                            </h1>
                        </label>
                        <textarea name="" id="textarea1" placeholder="">
                        </textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried, I really have, but I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to increase the size of the text box, when the page gets loaded, then the default size of the text box should cover the entire area above the save button instead of what is shown now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <style>

        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textarea1">
                            <h1 style='text-align:center;'>Please enter your notes here
                            </h1>
                        </label>
                        <textarea name="" id="textarea1" placeholder="" style="width:1246px;">
                        </textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>

        </script>
    </body>
</html>

Try this. I am not sure if this is what you need.
```

Comment: i need the height to be from top till the save button, but your answer was helpful, thanks

Comment: @samdonly1 can you elaborate how you want the height?

Comment: i want the height from the top of the page till the save button.

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution with css3 http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/
and http://jsfiddle.net/cuyJ4/15/ with jquery

css:

```
textarea { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```